# Do third party extenders for Canon exist?

Tags: canon, accessories, third-party, teleconverter

I was looking into extenders(Teleconverter) for Canon lenses, and they are quite expensive at around $450 for the [1.4x III](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/732113-USA/Canon_4409B002_Extender_EF_1_4X_III.html) or [2x III](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/732111-USA/Canon_4410B002_Extender_EF_2X_III.html). I know that extension tubes are a different story, and since they contain no optics the brand really doesn't matter. But what about for extenders? Do third party options exist and are they worth looking into?

Related: [Are there any downsides in using 2x extenders?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/889/are-there-any-downsides-in-using-2x-extenders)

Comment: I've only ever seen ones with no options or electronic linkages.

Comment: @ChrisF - Thanks for the comment. I certainly would like to have AF.

Comment: I wouldn't like to say for certain there aren't any - hence why I'm not answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party options do exist and are worth looking into. Sigma does make teleconverters, although I am not certain whether they will only fit certain Sigma lenses or also Canon ones. The teleconverters from Kenko/Tamron/Soligor (pretty much the same thing) are of interest because they lack the protrusion that Canon and Sigma ones have which have to slot into a similar opening in the lens; this means that the Kenko/Tamron/Soligor converters can be used on any lens you choose to mount it to and not only the longer tele lenses that are explicitly designed for use with converters. I have used an 1.4x Kenko converter with a Canon 100mm macro and an old 80-200/2.8L, neither of which are compatible with Canon teleconverters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, try the following search and it will filter the teleconverters to be compatible with Canon mount type.

Go [here](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Category_Teleconverters&ci=278&N=4288584246&cm_sp=Filters-_-Category-_-Teleconverters) and choose either Canon EOS or Canon FD (based on what you have) from the menu *Camera Mount Type* on the left side.

Unfortunately I can't add the link with the filters here cause it won't work.

Comment: How do the price compare to Canon. I know it's dangerous to talk numbers (as they go out of date) but are they half the price, a third of the price?

Comment: @ChrisF - The Kenko and Sigma 1.4x are about $250 USD. I wonder if they are comparable to the Canon though.

Comment: Also Bower (http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/829511-REG/Bower_SX4DGC_2x_DGII_Teleconverter_4.html) offers a 2x converter for $139. And you will be able to use Auto Focus. It's the first result in the search. You will have to read the reviews to check the quality though.