# Wide Angle Lens on a Step Down ring?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, wide-angle

I'm a beginner at photography and own a Canon 20D with two lens; a 50mm prime and a 17mm-85mm zoom.

I've purchases all my filters at 67mm to fit my zoom lens and use a [52mm - 67mm step up ring](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0013UOLBK/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to use them with my prime lens.

I'm looking at buying a [wide angle lens](http://www.amazon.co.uk/0-45x-Angle-Macro-Canon-Nikon/dp/B009ZCDN8U/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=3RTHVVENOWJPK&coliid=I22GNG78ZYUP5). My question is, will the same principal work? Can I buy a 67mm wide angle lens and use it on my 52mm prime without any trouble.

One of the reasons for the purchase of a wide angle is my cropped sensor makes the 50mm prime rather close - I'm hoping the wide angle will make it easier to capture more.

Many thanks for any help in advance.
Pete

Comment: Related: [What are the drawbacks of an extender (wide or teleconverter)?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29890/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-an-extender-wide-or-teleconverter)

Comment: Also kind of related (on the telephoto side): [What is a “2.2X Pro Telephoto” lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17591/what-is-a-2-2x-pro-telephoto-le)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, although the sellers label it as a *wide angle lens*, in reality what you are considering purchasing is more properly called a *wide angle conversion lens* because it screws onto and converts your existing lens to cover a wider field-of-view. In general the products sold in this price range aren't very good, and that is putting it nicely. There are some more expensive *wide angle conversion lenses*, such as those made by [Raynox](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/219741-REG/Raynox_HD_6600PRO_58_HD_6600_Pro_58mm_0_66x.html), but the largest size I'm aware they make fits on 58mm threads. And even those involve a fairly significant compromise in image quality.

The step up adapter *should* work on your 50mm lens, but I would be very surprised if the image quality were even anywhere near as good as your 17-85mm zoom zoomed to around 35mm. The magnification provided by the conversion lens is listed as 0.45x which should produce a field of view of around a 33-35mm lens when combined with a 50mm lens. Remember magnification is expressed in terms of coverage area, not focal length. In return for that modest improvement in angle of view, you will almost certainly see a substantial increase in vignetting, distortion (the fish-eye effect), and chromatic aberration (color separation that makes objects near the edge of the picture look blurry). Here is a [well written review](http://more4u2c.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/review-wide-angle-0-45x-add-on/) of a similar lens that goes into far more detail and provides test shots comparing using a *wide angle conversion lens* with a wide angle lens.

You would probably be much happier with the images you get by saving up for something like the EF 35mm f/2. Although it has been replaced by a newer (and more expensive) IS version, it is still available from many online retailers (at least here in the U.S.). Even the very inexpensive [Yongnuo 35mm f/2 for Canon EF mount](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00W4Z82ZO) should outperform an EF 50mm f/1.8 + wide angle conversion lens.

Comment: I make 0.45 * 50 to be 22.5, not 33-35

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer Michael and the review link is very helpful. I think I'll take your advice and put my pocket money towards a 35mm :-)

Comment: @MattGrum Unlike a sensor crop factor that is linear, magnification for screw on lenses is based on area, so 0.45x is area magnification. Focal length is linear. The √0.45 = 0.67. 0.67 X 50mm = 33.5mm. Most lenses with a focal length of 33mm are marketed as 35mm lenses.

Comment: The area magnification labeling is very interesting — I had no idea!

Comment: @mattdm it's misleading more than anything, since teleconverters are always specified in terms of focal length, not area. Imagine if Canon one day started calling all of their 1.4x TCs "2x" and their 2x "4x"...

Comment: @MattGrum Yeah, absolutely. Since focal length is our normal convention for representing field of view, and since field of view is what one cares about with this kind of converter, using anything else is ridiculous and borderline dishonest.

Answer (score 4):

Using a screw on wide converter with a fast lens will result in a poor quality image. If you need to shoot wide angle images at large apertures like f/1.8 then your options are limited to something like the Canon 28mm f/1.8 Sigma 30 f/1.4 both of which are around £350.

Alternatively upgrading your camera to the original 5D would cost a little more (~£450) but would act like a 0.4x wide converter that *improves*  image quality!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt, nice point about the 5D. I better get saving :-)