# Can I mount 0.4x, 52mm wide angle lens convertor on Nikon's 18-55mm, Ø55 kit lens?

Tags: nikon, lens-adapter, wide-angle, filter-diameter

I want to have an option to capture wide-angle shots. Since the wide-angle lens is expensive, I want to give a try to **0.4x wide-angle converter lenses**. I found one such lens here on [**amazon.de**](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00M95ABWQ/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

**QUESTION:** I found that all the lens converters have a specification that they can be mounted on the lens with  ***filter diameter 52 mm, 58 mm and 67 mm***. But I checked that my 18-55mm kit lens has a specification **Ø55**.

> Is it possible for me to use the above mentioned wide-angle lens
>   converter with my kit lens?

**My Camera:** Nikon D5600

Comment: You're better off using one that is the next size larger than your lens' filter threads, rather than the next size smaller. This is true of any type of screw-on filter/"lens". In which case your question is a duplicate of [Wide Angle Lens on a Step Down ring?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41669/15871)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need a step-down adapter, such as [this](https://www.amazon.de/vhbw-Adapter-Filteradapter-55mm-52mm-Panasonic/dp/B011R01EW4/ref=pd_sbs_421_1?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B011R01EW4&pd_rd_r=567acd66-59ae-11e8-812a-c379ca064baf&pd_rd_w=D7kfY&pd_rd_wg=sgv50&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_p=1662399603728955198&pf_rd_r=D5122XBD3NGDME6HK58T&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&psc=1&refRID=D5122XBD3NGDME6HK58T) with a 55mm thread into your kit lens, then a 52mm thread for the wide-angle converter.

Unfortunately... you will very quickly discover that these wide-angle adapters are not worth the money, however tempting they may appear.
I'm certain their entire purpose in life is to teach poor unsuspecting newbie photographers the meaning of the word 'vignette'.
At anything below 30mm focal length on your kit lens, you'll be able to see the dark circle round the edges of the frame formed by the adapter - & because your viewfinder only shows about 90% of the frame you're about to take, you discover that *after* you take the shot.
Also, as mentioned in comments, they are really unsharp. Mine doesn't display *huge* colour aberration, but it definitely adds a hazy glow to everything that disappears as soon as the adapter is removed.

Reason I know this... I fell for it too as a newbie. Used it once, put it in a drawer.

I would seriously consider saving up for even the cheapest 'real' wide angle lens.

*Edit*:
I dug mine out of the drawer & took this less than spectacular picture of the view from my workroom window @18mm with a 0.43x adaptor [so a 0.4x will be even worse] ;)
It's not out of focus, honestly, it's just not sharp across the entire frame.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size [but only jpg 60% quality to keep file size down]</sup>

*Late thought, for any other newbies who read this.*
Exactly the same false economy applies to cheap filters, UV, CPL, ND etc... don't fall for it; buy one good filter, bigger than you'll ever need, 77mm or so minimum, then get adaptor rings for all your lenses.
One purchase, many years of joy.
Far better than a drawer full of <strike>crap</strike> ...cheap stuff you'll never use again.

Comment: And don't forget to mention the very poor photo quality with such converters, especially at the corners, where they in most cases just produce colorful rainbows.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks for the reply. I just want to have it as an option. In the production description, they have mentioned that it comes with a converter ring, which can fit to all the lenses.

Comment: I added an example. Check the full size image linked to see just how fuzzy it is, even in the image centre. The vignetting is, of course, pretty spectacular at 18mm ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks for the example pic...it looks terrible ;)

Comment: Yup, indeed it does. It's generally one to be warned about rather than having to learn for yourself. Even though they're "as cheap as chips" the  results are just not worth the effort ;)